# Table Header not working with Sticky attribute

Tags: html, css

I trying to make the header of this table(.control-products-table) move when I move beyound the header. But not happening, what do I missing?
It should work but I thinking that I forgetting something

I already search for an answer, and looks like that I made. please help!!

https://dontpad.com/my/not/working/table

in the above link I put the code of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do not use overflow in the parent of the sticky element

You must remove [`overflow-auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) from the parent `div` for the `table`.

> The sticky positioning might not work if any parent element of the sticky element has an overflow property (like `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: scroll`, or `overflow: auto`) set on it.

You can [read more about](https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/) dealing with overflow and position sticky.

Also, set a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to the sticky header to allow the header to come in front of other elements when scrolling.

```css
thead > tr > th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

This can be the table:

```css
#content-container {
  padding-top: 55px;
}

.control-products-table {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.give-space {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.col-tanque,
.col-jacarepagua,
.col-vila,
.col-grajau,
.col-catete,
.col-pechincha,
.col-tijuca {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-right-color: #0d6efd;
  text-align: center;
}

.control-products-table td:last-child,
.control-products-table th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.col-product {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.col-request {
  background-color: #d3d3d3!important;
  --bs-table-bg-type: none!important;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col-form {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#form-buttons {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-removed-alert {
  padding: 0.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#request-products-table {
  font-size: 12px;
}

thead>tr>th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped control-products-table">
        <thead class="sticky-table-header">
          <tr>
            <th class="col-product"></th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-tanque">Tanque</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-jacarepagua">Jacarepagua</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-vila">Vila</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-grajau">Grajau</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-catete">Catete</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-pechincha">Pechincha</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="col-tijuca">Tijuca</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-product">Produto</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-tanque">Pedido</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-jacarepagua">Pedido</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-vila">Pedido</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-grajau">Pedido</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-catete">Pedido</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-pechincha">Pedido</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th class="col-tijuca">Pedido</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">100 PS SUPLEMENTO VITAMINICO PASSAROS 10GR</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADITIVO ANTIODOR PIPICAT BACTERICIDA 500G</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADITIVO ANTIODOR PIPICAT CAMPESTRE 500G</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADITIVO ANTIODOR PIPICAT FLORAL 500G</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADVOCATE COMBO CAO 3 PIPETAS 10-25KG - 2.5ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADVOCATE COMBO CAO 3 PIPETAS 25-40KG - 4ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADVOCATE COMBO CAO 3 PIPETAS 4-10KG - 1ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">0</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADVOCATE COMBO CAO 3 PIPETAS ATE 4KG - 0.4ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">0</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADVOCATE COMBO GATO 3 PIPETAS 4-8KG - 0.8ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">3.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">3.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">3</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">3.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">3</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">3.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">3</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">ADVOCATE COMBO GATO 3 PIPETAS ATE 4KG - 0.4ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">AFASTEPET FORTE 150ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">2.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">2</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-product">AFASTEPET FORTE 500ML</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-tanque">45</td>
            <td class="col-tanque col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua">0</td>
            <td class="col-jacarepagua col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">1.0</td>
            <td class="col-vila">0</td>
            <td class="col-vila col-request">1</td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau"></td>
            <td class="col-grajau col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete"></td>
            <td class="col-catete col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha"></td>
            <td class="col-pechincha col-request"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca"></td>
            <td class="col-tijuca col-request"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Using position sticky with overflow workaround

If, in any case, you need to stick with your solution and have both overflow and position sticky, you can add a fixed height to your overflowing element like `80vh` and make it work, but keep in mind it does not work everywhere and in every situation.

It will be something like:

HTML:

```html
<div class="col overflow-auto parent">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parent {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

As per your last request for making the first column sticky. You can do the same thing as the table header.

```css
.control-products-table th.col-product,
.control-products-table td.col-product {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

/* To keep your table consistent and allow the right element to come over other when scrolling */
.control-products-table th.col-product {
  z-index: 101;
}

.control-products-table td.col-product {
  z-index: 99;
}
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind it's always best to just post your code abstractions to let other users identify issues within your code more easily.

Comment: Hey SMAKSS, Thanks for your answer. I'll be in attention by your NOTE for the next questions. Does it have a solution without removing `overflow: hidden;`? I need that, because the table has many columns. And another doubt that I had, was about the first column. Is possible it goes to the right?

Comment: @DiogoAmaral If you follow the article that I shared in the read-more-about sentence, you can find a workaround for this. However, it does not always work as expected in all browsers. For your second part of the question, I did not understand what you were trying to point out, please elaborate.

Comment: @DiogoAmaral I also, updated the answer to reflect your need for the combination of overflow and sticky position.

Comment: SMAKSS thank you. It work perfectly. And thank you for the link with more explanation. About my second doubt, I'll try to explain better. Well... My table has many columns, that's why I need the overflow, at the same time, I want to look the data that are to the right of table, and when I go to the right of table I dont know about the first Column, which is the product that I'm reading about. Does have anyway to make the first column of table "stickable" to the right?

Comment: @DiogoAmaral Yes, it's possible I've updated the answer accordingly and added extra CSS for it. P.S. I had to delete some of the table contents to extend my answer.